# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array Not making any sense at all

Tags: php

I have the fatal error coming up in the error log but it is not affecting the application at all for some reason. This is the code that is running and it makes no sense why it generating the PHP error.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $tournament['num_score_fields']; $i++) {

            $scoresArrayTemp = array(
                'score',
                'dist',
                'dateShot',
                'tens', 
                'nines'
                );

            foreach($scoresArrayTemp AS $val){
                if(empty($scores[$i][$val])){
                    $scores[$i][$val] = ''; 
                }
            }
}
```

The error is generated by this line

```
$scores[$i][$val] = '';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Based on answer 1 I changed code to this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $tournament['num_score_fields']; $i++) {


            $scoresArrayTemp = array(
                'score'=>'',
                'dist'=>'',
                'dateShot'=>'',
                'tens'=>'', 
                'nines'=>''
                );

            if(!is_array($scores[$i])){
                $scores[$i] = $scoresArrayTemp;
            }

            echo $scores[$i]['score'];
}
```

Still gets the error on the last line when echoing out the variable

Comment: what is $scores?  based on the error message scores appears to be a string? since $string[1] would give you a string offset in php

Comment: $scores is an array and always will be an array that is looked after further up the code.

Comment: are you 100% sure it is an array at this scope (Since we don't see all the code). Since PHP appears to be parsing `$scores[$i][$val]`as `($scores[$i])[$val]`.  And it `$scores` was a string you would have (string offset)[$val] and the error message makes perfect sense.  Try var dumping $scores, inside the loop and see what it shows.

Answer (score 0):

`$scores[$i]` is not an array, so PHP is preventing you from assigning a value to the index at `$val`. You probably want this:

```
if(is_array($scores[$i]) && empty($scores[$i][$val])){
    $scores[$i][$val] = ''; 
}
```

Comment: Updated the code in question to check array status if not array then make it one but still the same error comes up...the odd part is that nothing breaks if I print_r the array is present with full structure.

Answer (score 0):

i made some alteration in your code to check where the problem was:

```
<?php
$tournament['num_score_fields'] = 10;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $tournament['num_score_fields']; $i++) {

        $scoresArrayTemp = array(
            'score',
            'dist',
            'dateShot',
            'tens', 
            'nines'
            );

        foreach($scoresArrayTemp AS $val){
            if(empty($scores[$i][$val])){
                $scores[$i][$val] = ''; 
                echo 'a';
            }
        }
}

?>
```

and **the output was :**

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

dude there is no error out here.. it could be due to any other reason. check the code from top to bottom again or show what exact error is coming.

Comment: That is what I was finding, after further investigation I am finding that the error is not being logged until data is posted from the form.

The strange part is that the function that houses this code is not used during the post process. 

I am going to have to dig deeper into this.